# probability problem (rolling a die)

Tags: probability

Can someone help please?  Brian rolls a fair die 10 times.  What is the probability that he rolls exactly 6 fours?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Please edit your post to include yours thoughts on the problem.

Comment: See the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 10 roles of the    the dice let $X$ denote  the number of getting    4's .It is obvious that $X$  follows a binomial distribution with $n=10$ and $p=1/6$.Hence,
$$P(X=6)=\binom{10}{6}.p^6(1-p)^4$$.Or,
$$P(X=6)=\binom{10}{4}\frac{1}{6^6}\frac{5^4}{6^4}$$